# Non static field cannot be referenced from a static context- Main method

Tags: java, class, methods, static, program-entry-point

I have 2 classes in my `Spring-Boot` application:

-Tasks

-Runner

The runner class contains my `main` method where I try to call a method from my Tasks class:

**Runner:**

```
@Component
public class Runner {

    Tasks tasks;    

    @Autowired
    public void setTasks(Tasks tasks){
        this.tasks=tasks;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

    //error being caused by below line
    tasks.createTaskList();

    }
```

**Tasks Class:**

```
@Service
public class Tasks {

    public void createTaskList() {

    //my code
    }


    //other methods 


}
```

In my Runner, when I try to call the createTaskList() method in the Tasks class I get the following error:

```
Non static field 'tasks' cannot be referenced from a static context
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch, that post does not fully answer the OP's question.  Since it is a spring boot application, the OP can't just create a static instance since injected beans are involved.

Comment: Thanks @HankD, what else do you suggest?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch, I would refer them to Krzysztof Wolny's answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199999/how-does-a-spring-boot-console-based-application-work. It shows them how to create a `main()` like non-static `run()` method that could access injected beans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main method is `static` meaning that it belongs to the class and not some object. As such, it a static context cannot reference an instance variable because it wouldn't know what instance of `Runner` it would use if there even was one.

In short, the solution is to make your `Tasks` object `static` in the `Runner` class.