# Application startup failed java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/StopWatch$TaskInfo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have developed a batch processing program using Spring Boot 1.4.2, which takes a long time (about 5 hours) to execute. After about 5 hours passes since the program launches, it finishes execution with an error message below:

```
20:49:01.324 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/StopWatch$TaskInfo
    at org.springframework.util.StopWatch.stop(StopWatch.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.example.Main.main(Main.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.util.StopWatch$TaskInfo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringBootExceptionHandler
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringBootExceptionHandler(SpringApplication.java:903)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.registerLoggedException(SpringApplication.java:850)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:840)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:816)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at jp.co.cyberagent.leeds.article_batches.ArticleBatchesApplication.main(ArticleBatchesApplication.java:25)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringBootExceptionHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more
```

It seems that I am missing some dependencies on Spring Framework, but I don't know what I really need.

Here's my `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'article-batches'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.ca-tools.org/content/groups/public/"
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.1.1')
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.1.7'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.40'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.2'
    compile group: 'org.mybatis', name: 'mybatis-typehandlers-jsr310', version: '1.0.1'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. My main process was written in `CommandLineRunner#run` method, but it is wrong way to write main process in `run` method as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199999/how-does-a-spring-boot-console-based-application-work#comment59024179_29774201) says in another question.

I followed the comment and wrote my main process like below, then the problem has gone away.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        final AppBean app = context.getBean(AppBean.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```